# AWS MediaConvert Throws Error 1076 for Safari Recored Videos

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, aws-sdk, video-processing, aws-media-convert

I'm getting this error
`Demuxer: [ReadPacketData File read failed - end of file hit at length [13155941]. Is file truncated?]` while trying to process the video with AWS Mediaconvert.
The video is being recorded from the ios safari/chrome browsers with the Mimetype of `video/mp4`.
I'm using the npm module `aws-sdk`.

It working fine for all the videos (`video/mp4` and other formats as well) selected using file input (means from my device)

Just for an update: Using AWS Elastic Transcoder works with safari recorded videos.

Answer (score 0):

That error is most likely because the source file contained variable size track fragment offsets, which is a characteristic of MediaRecorder outputs.  MediaConvert was enhanced with the ability to handle these types of inputs as of November 11th, 2021, so I would recommend testing the assets again.

If you continue to have issues, you can try remuxing the source file in ffmpeg with a command such as:

`ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c copy remuxed_source.mp4`

Comment: yeah using ffmpeg solves the problem but i don't wanna use ffmpeg is quite large and takes more time to remuxing it. also i guess need to test this again with the mediaconvert . i think it may work now inside mediaconvert

Comment: Also with Mediaconvert it solves the issue but now it rotates the video by 90deg which should not do that.

Comment: Solution for Rotation Issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954677/11216915

Comment: I just received this error in MediaConvert. It's still not fixed.